# Removing focus border outline on bootstrap select

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [this](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) plugin in my project, and trying to remove the blue border on focuse on the select. I have tried by setting the outline to none, like this:

```
*:focus {
  outline: 0!important;
}
```

I have also tried with `outline:none` , but it is not working, how can I remove the outline from it?

I am using the same html as suggested in the plugin docs:

```
<select name="position" value="{{ $player->position or  old('position') }}" class="selectpicker show-menu-arrow form-control" multiple data-max-options="3" data-icon-base="ion" data-tick-icon="ion-checkmark-round" title="Choose positions (max 3)" required>
     @foreach($positions as $key => $value)
        <option data-subtext="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
     @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: `outline: none;` works fine for me.

Comment: Have you checked on another browser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed it with this:

```
.bootstrap-select .btn:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}
```

and you should add it at the end of your css code after the **bootstrap-select.css**